# Writing portable man pages

Tags: manpage, troff

If I want to write man pages which are portable between different Unix-like systems, which source language standard should I use? Or can I simply assume that GNU troff (groff) is available everywhere?

Comment: troff is typically available in a unix-y install that expects to display manpages.

Comment: @pvg Still, it's not clear which features in groff that are portable. GNU software tends to add anything that might be useful to someone.

Comment: I think manpages use a fairly constrained subset and the fact that some unixes use groff (Linux, OS X) is incidental. OpenBSD seems to have written their own formatter a few years ago because, well, OpenBSD. But I think the sanest thing is to use one of the many higher-level systems that know how to spit out manpages. They seem to generate portable-enough manpages.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at https://www.troff.org/macros.html, under `man`, it lists two guides for writing man pages.

- [THE LINUX MAN-PAGE-HOWTO](http://www.schweikhardt.net/man_page_howto.html) by Jens Schweikhardt
- [Writing Effective Manual Pages](http://home.windstream.net/kollar/groff/effman.html) by Larry Kollar

In general, they both recommend avoiding using additional preprocessors such as `tbl`, `pic`, or `eqn` especially if you want to maximize portability.

Man pages use the `an` macro package.  This was done so when you called it with the `-m` macro option it shows as `troff -man`.  To find the macros defined by the `an` macro package, you should look for files matching either `tmac.an*` (for UNIX/BSD systems) or `an*.tmac` (for Linux systems).  For example, on RHEL/CentOS it would be:

```
/usr/share/groff/1.18.1.4/tmac/an.tmac which refers to
/usr/share/groff/1.18.1.4/tmac/andoc.tmac which refers to
/usr/share/groff/1.18.1.4/tmac/an-old.tmac which defines most of the macros
```

These files are part of the groff package.